# Deserializing using xml attribute name -> property

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

say I have the following XML

```
<doc>
    <float name="score">7.8753223</float>
    <str name="author">asdadsad</str>
    <str name="body">...</str>
    <str name="category">haelth-safety</str>
</doc>
```

and the following class:

```
public class Doc{
    public double Score { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Body{ get; set; }
    public string Category{ get; set; }
}
```

How can I tell the serializer to map the data to the c# properties using xml attribute name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing xml using XDocument, solr results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366440/parsing-xml-using-xdocument-solr-results)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can do it with declarative (attributed) serialization for xml format you specified. If you want to use declarative serialization, change format to something like this:

```
<doc>
    <score>7.8889798</score>
    <author>agfdfg</author>
    <body>...</body>
    <category>haleth safet</category>
</doc>
```

And use XmlElementAttribute to specify corresponding element names for the properties you serialize.

Comment: The XML comes from Solr so is out of my control :/

Comment: Then you ave to customize serialization. Google for `IXmlSerializable`.